# Create link with 'name' attribute only using l() function

Tags: navigation

Is it possible to create a link using Drupal's l() function without an href? For example, I'd like to create a link like the following:

```
<a name="my-anchor">A link here</a>
```

However, this seems to not be possible. The closest I can come is to use the following:

```
l(t('A link here'), '', array('external' => TRUE, 'attributes' => array('name' => 'my-anchor')));
```

This outputs:

```
<a href name="my-anchor">A link here</a>
```

... and that's not valid HTML. It also causes slightly strange behavior in some browsers depending on the CSS applied...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly this cannot be accomplish with the [l](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7) function because the href is hard-coded in the theme_link theme function.

You can accomplish this by using the html_tag theme function.

It'll look something like this

```
return theme('html_tag', array('element' => array('#tag' => 'a', '#value' => 'A link here', '#attributes' => array('name' => 'my-anchor'))));
```

This will return

```
<a name="my-anchor">A link here</a>
```

Is a bit more work, but it does give you a properly formatted a tag with out the href.

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be done with l() only, since the href attribute is hard-coded in theme_link().

You could, however, override this them function, and add an extra key to the options array (something like 'anchor' => TRUE').

Comment: Basically, yes. I up toed, but chose Eric's answer instead, as it's an easier solution for a one-off use.

Comment: s/up toed/upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can create an `<a>` tag with Drupal without the `href` attribute. Doing so would be invalid HTML as `href` is a required attribute for `<a>` tags so it is not something I would suggest doing anyways.

Why don't you create a tag with `href="#"`or something similar?

Comment: According to the W3C spec, you can have <a> tags without an href... http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1 - to be used for anchors in a document...